# Failed to set up listener: SocketException: Cannot assign requested address

Tags: mongodb

While launching MongoDB getting this error.

> Failed to set up listener: SocketException: Cannot assign requested address.

Screenshot:
[image: Screenhshot]

Comment: Screenshots of text look terrible on mobile devices.

Answer (score 0):

You already have a server running on the port that this server is trying to use.